# Double Integral Problem- Symmetry

Tags: calculus

I was trying to calculate the following integral but the result is zero. But we know that the area can't be zero here so do I have to use some symmetry? 
$$\int_{2}^{4} \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1-x-xy+x^2y \right) \, dx \, dy$$

Comment: Why do you think this is "some" area? And if so, then the area of *what*? And indeed: the integral equals zero.

Comment: The answer _can_ be zero, but in your case it isn't (it's $-4$). The easiest geometrical interpretation would be a (signed) **volume**, not a signed area. Perhaps you can show your calculations?

Comment: Areas under curves can evaluate to zero, for example $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x dx =0$$

Comment: @StackTD How did you get $\;-4\;$ ? I got zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio Now it's $0$, but before the edit the integrand was $1-x-xy\color{red}{-}x^2y$ instead of $1-x-xy+x^2y$...

Comment: @StackTD Thanks, I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to calculate the following integral but the result is zero. But we know that the area cant be zero here so do i have to use some symmetry ?

Your result is correct, the integral is zero.

Area and volume can't be negative, but the geometrical interpretation of an integral gives you a so called *signed* area or volume. Integrals can be zero, or even negative.

For an integral of a function of one variable, the result can be seen as a *signed area* where the contribution of area *under* the $x$-axis gets a minus sign. If you have an equal amount of area above as below the $x$ axis, the integral will be zero; e.g. for a full period of the sine function:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x \, \mbox{d}x = 0$$

For an integral of a function of two variables, such as in your example, the straightforward interpretation would be a *signed volume* of the region bounded by the $xy$-plane and the graph of the integrand $z=f(x,y)$. In the same way, contributions of volume *under* the $xy$-plane get a minus sign. So you *can* get $0$ as a result of a double integral: there will be an equal amount of volume above as below the $xy$-plane.